# Can't install font for libre office

Tags: 17.10, libreoffice, fonts, macosx

How can I install font for libre office in Ubuntu and Mac os?

I would like to install font `KHMERKEP.ttf` to support font in my file word document that I open in libre office. I tried to install by double click on font file above, and click on install already, but after I open my file word document again, font name `KHMERKEP` still not available in my libre office.

[image]

Please kindly help me to install to install font in libre office, Thanks.

Comment: @user535733, I already edited my question, it the same problem, after I double click on font file and click install already, but still not found in libre office. Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart libreoffice?

Comment: @user535733, yes I restart already, but still not show new font.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Following some of the other threads on this topic I put the ttf files in usr/share/fonts

I tried putting the whole (unzipped) ttf folder with its enclosed ttf file into the fonts folder, restarted, but no effect.  It tried putting just the ttf file in the fonts folder, no effect.

I tried putting the file and file in folder separately in some of the other folders, specifically opentype and truetype and no change.

It was when I looked inside the truetype folder that I recognized some of the installed fonts that were already in my Libre, specificlally "abyssinica."

I tried putting the ttf file (no folder) directly into the abyssinica folder, installed (by double clicking the ttf) and then restarting Libre.  It took.  I've now added 5 new fonts.

bottom line, I put the ttf file here:

usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica

and the new fonts appear in Libre and I'm able to write with them.